# Show only youtube url using regex+php

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have created custom video type widget in wordpress. Where User can
                 add video url by using add media option. Here the issue is if user
                 is adding youtube url along with some text (mixture of texts and urls) 
                 then front end showing both texts and videos there. I want to split
                 youtube url from that.

Example :

```
Eros nisi adipiscing penatibus! Phasellus? A. Dapibus etiam massa! Phasellus lacus, purus tempor! Sagittis, montes rhoncus dolor? Dolor nec, in risus. Augue placerat dis nisi velit enim magnis lorem.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdvEdMMtNMY

Nisi mus ut magnis vel porta dignissim lectus enim et diam tincidunt sagittis parturient turpis aliquet nunc adipiscing dolor parturient? Auctor! Elementum ultricies parturient porttitor urna hac. Massa elementum dis.
```

result I want :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdvEdMMtNMY (youtube url only)
```

I know regex is the function for that in php
             but I dont how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/https?:..www\.youtube\.com.\S*\s/", $myText, $treffer);
print_r($treffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not working

Comment: @jka I've just tested it, it is working http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ae672a05791d672bddfda2f61a9c2709c2f3037

Comment: Ya its working but only for http not for https

Comment: @jka that's a problem :) see the edit